# Compile error during building react-native app for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, llvm-clang

I have a `react-native` project that it built and worked perfectly on `Android` but when I want to build it in `ios` I always get errors that most of them are related to `com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`. and the `'Operation not permitted'`. I carefully follow the instruction of installing packages and for testing, I just removed some of the packages and then I get the same error again. How can I solve these errors?

FYI: When I build a new `react-native` project, there is no problem during building it.

```
CompileC /Users/mehdi/Documents/chandkhat/front-end/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphones
imulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Conv.o /Users/mehdi/Documents/chandkhat/front-end/node_modules/react-nativ
e/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/Conv.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
```

`error: unable to open output file '/Users/mehdi/Documents/chandkhat/front-end/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.b
uild/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Conv.o': 'Operation not permitted'`